# Letters in Xcode Project Navigator

Tags: xcode

I want to know the meaning of the letters in the project navigator in Xcode; (Ms & A) [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are for source control. M stands for Modified. A stands for Added. This is so you know what files have changed since the last commit of your project.

It's all explained on this support page http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html

Comment: Thx, I never thought it had to do with repositories lol we use a third party one XD